# How to setup noreply@<domain> google Cloud Composer?

Tags: sendgrid, google-cloud-composer

I am trying to use sendGrid with Google Cloud Composer and providing SENDGRID_MAIL_FROM value noreply-composer@domain (noreply-composer@gmail.com), while running the airflow dag receiving error 403: Forbidden
. I did some research and got to know that from should be verified in the sender list. But if I just want to send alert mail with **noreply** user, this username physically doesn't exist and can not be verified.

Does anybody know workaround for the same, so I can send the mail with noreply username?

Comment: Actually sender [validation](https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/sender-identity/) performs either through Single Sender Verification or Domain Authentication, hence a valid email has to be used, have you read this [article](https://sendgrid.com/blog/why-you-should-not-use-noreplydomain-com-in-your-emails/)?

Comment: Thanks ... Do you suggest (@Nick_kh) that we need to set up Domain Authentication, to make it work in this way (noreply@<domain>.com)

Comment: Probably it will help though, just check my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating more to my comment, according to [SendGrid](https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/sender-identity/) documentation pages, each sender identity should be verified using either *Domain Authentication* or *Single Sender Verification*. Based on the intro of *Single Sender Verification* as of most common use case restriction:

> You can send only from the address you verify rather than any address
> on an authenticated domain.

With said this, you might have to [validate](https://sendgrid.com/docs/ui/sending-email/sender-verification/) email account ownership for each `FROM` email address entry.

*Domain Authentication* will probably help to overcome the above mentioned limitation, however it requires to edit DNS records of the domain provider name resolution service:

> You can send from any email address on your authenticated domain.

After adding `CNAME`, `TEXT` or `MX` particular records to your DNS service, they need to be validated in [SendGrid UI](https://sendgrid.com/docs/ui/account-and-settings/how-to-set-up-domain-authentication/#verifying-your-dns).

I encourage you to check out the relevant [tutorial](https://sendgrid.com/docs/ui/account-and-settings/how-to-set-up-domain-authentication) to give more essential outcome.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this info... @Nick_kh. somehow I have configured the domain authentication in SendGrid. But now sendgrid is sending mail from any user of authenticated domain, can we specify the users of authenticated domain in SendGrid.  I did some research on  SendGrid document which is suggesting to add info in subuser management but I have free subscription of sendGrid which doesn't provide access for the same. Could you please suggest me whether subuser management will work or there is something else needs to be done?

Comment: Hi @Ashish Dhamu, your additional comment is a good subject for a new Stack [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) though, as it is a bit out of context for original topic. Composing a new question gives more opportunities to find the sufficient solution.

Comment: Hi @Nick_kh, actually I asked the question in the new stack but still, no response received so thought of asking you here :), could you please answer it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64269850/why-sendgrid-is-allowing-sending-mail-from-any-user-of-authenticated-domain) if you have any suggestion?

Comment: If you haven't done it yet, I would recommend to reach out to SendGrid [support](https://sendgrid.com/docs/ui/account-and-settings/support/) team for further assistance as I'm not sure whether it is a feasible approach within SenGrid.