# Why SendGrid is allowing sending mail from any user of authenticated domain?

Tags: sendgrid

I have authenticated my domain in the SendGrid, now when I specify any email (with authenticated domain) it will send the mail. I want to restrict this to **Fromuser@domain.com**.

Let's say I want to restrict sending mail for this user noreply@domain.com, so that it can not be miss used by any other sender from the organization. Is this possible in SendGrid?